# Server To Simply Call REST API's Then Forward The Response(s) To A Document Database?

Tags: rest, web-services, polling

The customer wants to poll (fetch) data from thousands of devices which offer REST API's. They want to run their own server, in other words they don't want to use any particular cloud offering.

Is there a known open source system that does such a job? I'm thinking of a Node.js server but the customer seems to want something easier to manage/code than that.

All the server needs to do is call (GET) particular REST endpoints then forward the entire response paylod (JSON) to a document database.

Comment: Elaborate on what is hard about a Node.js server from the perspective of your customer.

Comment: I floated the idea of building it in Node and their response was "we want something that the end customer can take and expand once we're done." I hear you though. I think it's a matter of my partner not being familiar w Node? They seem keen on Python. I was just wondering if there was already something built for extracting data. UI based for non developers.

Comment: If you're looking for an piece of software to solve an issue, stack overflow isn't the place. If the customer somehow puts more weight in python than node to solve a problem, this also doesn't seem like a programming issue. If they think python is more likely going to be maintainable by others, use python.

Answer (score 0):

Noone responded with an answer. I think the answer is - it's called a cron job, or a scheduled task, and is a feature of industry standard operating systems. This could run a basic server such as Python or Node.js which could make the API calls and forward the responses to a data lake or database.

Comment: Well, that will get you *schedules* for your tasks (what cron calls "commands"), but you'll still need some software to execute those tasks.

Comment: Good point. I need to amend my answer.